# Function call analysis using Clang

Tags: clang, transformation

I am using clang to do some kind of source to source transformation. I would like to do the following:

I have some class of functions in C which are `va_arg` functions, e.g `printf()`. There might be a number of calls to `printf()` in the source file. I want to parse the source code and find all these calls to `printf()`. Furthermore, I want to find the type of arguments that are passed to `printf()`. So, if i have something like

```
int a, b, c;
printf("%d%d%d", a, b, c);
```

I want to be able to figure out that the particular call to `printf` is of type `printf(char*, int, int, int)`. I don't particularly care about qualifiers.

Could someone tell me how I should go about doing this in clang? Any example doing anything similar to this would be welcome. If you could even tell me what all classes I should be looking at and in brief tell me the flow that I should follow, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You should write an ASTConsumer. The first thing to look at is the code in [examples/PrintFunctionNames](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/examples/PrintFunctionNames/PrintFunctionNames.cpp?view=markup) which is a very simple ASTConsumer.

One way to find all the calls to printf is through the [RecursiveASTVisitor](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html), looking for the [CallExpr](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CallExpr.html) nodes. These nodes have getNumArgs() and getArg(n) which lets you examine the arguments. You can call expr->getType() on those expressions to get their types.